# Changing kAuthority to consumers doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm using the [MSAL Preview](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc) for iOS and this [swift sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios-swift-native-v2).

Based on the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints), I should be using **consumers** not **common** to force it to Personal accounts only.

In the [ViewDidLoad function](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios-swift-native-v2/blob/323c9e884968f45760f62a5b9aef3e4b6e8127ed/MSALiOS/ViewController.swift#L206)

```
self.applicationContext = try MSALPublicClientApplication.init(clientId: kClientID, authority: kAuthority)
```

Changing kAuthority to

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

Should lock it to consumer accounts only.

But this seems to throw an error of "**This doesn't look like a work or school email. You can't sign in here iwth a personal account. User your work or school account instead.**" It does work for that kAuthority if i put in org account.

If i change to

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

It allows allows org in but not consumer account.

Both work if I set back to code sample default of

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

I have noticed that if I hit this in a browser

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=##clientid##&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read&state=12345
```

this works fine in a browser. So I don't think its an application configuration issue. unless its to do with native vs web calling this?

I noticed in the [latest sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios-swift-native-v2) , kAuthority has been shortened.

```
let kAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/"
```

Tried this and doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with the engineering team in [GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/issues/274) and they fixed a back end problem. This is now resolved.